# I can´t upload documents to Google Sites from url using Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to upload files to Google Sites using the Url from my G-Drive. I am using this code, it is running but when I refresh the site the files don´t upload.

```
function uploadFiles(url, h) {  
    try {
    var url = "myFileUrl";
    var site = SitesApp.getSite("mySite", "myPage");
    var page = site.getAllDescendants()[0];
    var id = getIdFrom(url); // function that I have that gives you the id of an url
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
    var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(blob);
    return attachment.getUrl(); 
     }
    catch(error)  
{
    return error.toString();  
}
```

Comment: See [mcve]. Was there a error or url `return`ed?

Answer (score 0):

There was no error when I ran it. I already solved this problem with a code bellow, but now I have a new one. When I upload the file it uploads as a .html file, and I want to upload it as .pptx or . xls depending on what type of document it is.

```
function uploadblob() { 
      var url = "myFileUrl;
      var site = SitesApp.getSite("mySite", "myPage");
      var page = site.getAllDescendants()[0];
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
      var attach = page.addHostedAttachment(blob);
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to pen a new post.